# Help with getting linux Gpib on pi

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://xdevs.com/guide/ni_gpib_rpi/
but I am getting stuck on the 8th step because on my pi I dont have the directory "/home/gpib" please help

I was wondering is it just that i have to go out and download the linux-gpib package and make a directory called "/home/gpib" and just extract the package there and do the make/install

Comment: I think the problem is step 8 gives this directory /home/gpib/linux-gpib-3.2.21# make, but I think this is the directory needed /home/linux-gpib/linux-gpib-code/linux-gpib/linux-gpib-3.2.21

Comment: im sorry that does not exist either

Comment: does a linux-gpib-3.2.21 directory exist anywhere in your home directory? You can use the find command to check find ~ -name "linux-gpib-3.2.21"

Comment: i did the command and it return something that looked like this
pi#  find ~ -name "linux-gpib-3.2.21"
pi#

Comment: so no i believe

Comment: Are you sure that the version used in the tutorial is what you are using? try running this: sudo find / -name "linux-gpib-*"

Comment: yah nothing there either but i found that this tutorial might have some answers its kinda vague though http://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/using-a-raspberry-pi-with-linux-gpib-and-a-beiming-or-agilent-usb-gpib-adapter/

Answer (score 1):

Step 5) lists:

> root@tin:/home/# mkdir linux-gpib
>   root@tin:/home/# cd linux-gpib

The required directory is created before step 8). You might just have missed that piece while working through the list.

Comment: no actually its supose to be "/home/gpib" not "/home/linux-gpib" i believe sorry